# Почему Фаерфокс делает отображение по-своему, хотя везде все нормально?

Tags: html, firefox, css

Добрый вечер! Прошу помочь с проблемой браузера Фаерфокс любого, в том числе и последнего.

Есть сайт: http://algoritmproject.ru/o-kompanii.php

Там есть шапочка на страничке, под основной шапкой, в которой выводится название страницы. Во всех браузерах, даже в дедушке IE 6, 8, 9, эта шапка отображается корректно, никуда не наезжает и т.п.

Пусть весь сайт в ИЕ 6, 8, 9 не оптимизирован, но этот элемент отображает корректно!

В опере, и хроме, и в последнем ИЕ тоже все идеально относительно данного элемента. Но вот фаерфокс доставляет...

Напрочь все косит на сайте, и причем это не первая такая фишка, на другом сайте он некорректно отображал позиционирование элемента с Абсолютной позицией, ошибался на 4 пикселя! Хотя также все остальные браузеры проблем не имели.

Прошу помочь, в чем у этого дурацкого фаерфокса проблема? Может быть, я кривой, но если бы я был кривым, то везде было бы криво...

Прошу вашей помощи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Проблема в теге section+overflow, если убрать section, то все нормально. Но почему он так себя ведет я не выяснил.

Comment: Переименовал section в div. Заново сделал данный блок, указав картинку бэкграундом, чуть налезать стало и в других браузерах, поправил, но фаерфокс - это демон какой-то! Там налезает опять по-крупному... И я не могу понять, как так, overflow у меня вообще нету больше...

Comment: Все разобрался. Добавил <div class="clearfix"></div> после хэдера и все заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё дата съезжает в старом браузере.
Потому что в css `.date .month` надо убрать `float: left;`.
А `.date .year` добавить `float: left;`.

И вместо span поставить div.

[image]

[image]